# Get index of hidden cell in a table with Responsive extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a jQuery DataTables built and a button with a "checking" class in one of its cells, I would like to get the index of the cell that contains that button once I click the button.

In order to reach this I have been using the following code:

```
$("#table tbody").on('click','.checking',function(){
    var index = '';
    index = $("#table").DataTable().cell($(this).parents('td')).index();
    console.log(index);
});
```

This has been working fine when the cell hasn't been hidden by the Responsive extension of the DataTables, however when that field is hidden this function throws an `undefined` value.

See the button "Go" on the screenshot below.

[image: Datatable Image]

Comment: If the cell is hidden which I assume has the Go Button, how do you click on it?

Comment: Once you press a little button you are able to view the fields hidden by the responsive, hence you are able to click on that button. Hope I've clarified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### CAUSE

When Responsive extension hides a column, by default it places all content into a separate `tr` node with one single `td` node as a list with multiple `li` nodes.

When your cell becomes hidden, code `cell($(this).parents('td'))` stops working because of the different markup.

#### SOLUTION

- **DataTables 1.10.11+** and **Responsive 2.0.2+** only

  ```
  $('#table tbody').on('click','.checking',function(){
      var index = $('#table').DataTable().cell($(this).closest('td, li')).index();
      console.log(index);
  });
  ```

  See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mq3sjt7g/3/) for code and demonstration.
- **DataTables 1.10+** and **Responsive 1.0.3+**

  This method uses deprecated method [`responsive.index()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.index()) which may be removed in future versions and its use is discouraged.

  ```
  $('#example tbody').on('click','.checking',function(){
      var $cellNode = $(this).closest('td, li');        

      var cell;
      if($cellNode.is('td')){
         cell = $('#example').DataTable().cell($cellNode);
      } else {
         var cellIdx = $('#example').DataTable().responsive.index($cellNode);
         cell = $('#example').DataTable().cell($cellNode);
      }

      var index = cell.index();
      console.log(index);
  });
  ```

  See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mq3sjt7g/2/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank you Sir, you don't know how useful this will be on the project I'm working on, have a nice day.